# How to convert c++ QString parameter to c# string

Tags: c#, qt, easyhook

I'm trying to hook the `QPainter::drawText` function in another application by injecting my DLL and detour the `QPainter::drawText` function to my own application. I'm doing this because the other application does not expose a usable API and I want to do some basic statistical analysis on the data I'm getting.

All is working fine: I see the `QPainter::drawText` functions being called, but I'm unable to convert the `QString` parameter to anything useful. All I get is two characters when I Marshall the `QString` parameter as `LPWStr`.

I'm no C++ superhero, so I'm a bit lost. I think I'm looking at some pointer or reference because of the two characters I get for each call, but I'm not sure. After a few nights trying to make sense of it I'm close to the point of giving up.

I've demangled the `QPainter::drawText` function (found using Dependency Walker: `?drawText@QPainter@@QAEXABVQRect@@HABVQString@@PAV2@@Z`) with https://demangler.com/ and it comes up with this function declaration:

```c
public: void __thiscall QPainter::drawText(class QRect const &,int,class QString const &,class QRect *)
```

I've converted this into the following DllImport (I substituted the `QRect` and `Qstring` classes to `IntPtr`, because I have no idea how to convert them to C#).

```cs
    [DllImport("Qt5Gui.dll", SetLastError = true,  CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall, EntryPoint = "?drawText@QPainter@@QAEXABVQRect@@HABVQString@@PAV2@@Z")]
    public static extern void QPainter_drawText(IntPtr obj, IntPtr p1, int p2, IntPtr p3, IntPtr p4);
```

This is what I have so far:

**Detouring Qt QPainter::drawText**

```cs
    LocalHook QPainter_drawTextHook;

    [DllImport("Qt5Gui.dll", SetLastError = true,  CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall, EntryPoint = "?drawText@QPainter@@QAEXABVQRect@@HABVQString@@PAV2@@Z")]
    public static extern void QPainter_drawText(IntPtr obj, IntPtr p1, int p2, IntPtr p3, IntPtr p4);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    delegate void TQPainter_drawText(IntPtr obj, IntPtr p1, int p2, IntPtr p3, IntPtr p4);

    static void QPainter_drawText_Hooked(IntPtr obj, IntPtr p1, int p2, IntPtr p3, IntPtr p4)
    {
        var qs3 = (QString)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p3, typeof(QString));

        try
        {
            ((Main)HookRuntimeInfo.Callback).Interface.GotQPainter_drawText(qs3.ToString());
            QPainter_drawText(obj, p1, p2, p3, p4);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ((Main)HookRuntimeInfo.Callback).Interface.ErrorHandler(ex);
        }
    }
```

**Create QPainter::drawText detour**

```cs
            QPainter_drawTextHook = LocalHook.Create(
                                        LocalHook.GetProcAddress("Qt5Gui.dll", "?drawText@QPainter@@QAEXABVQRect@@HABVQString@@PAV2@@Z"),
                                        new TQPainter_drawText(QPainter_drawText_Hooked), 
                                        this);

            QPainter_drawTextHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
```

**Update 2016-1-31**
Thus far I have found this (see https://github.com/mono/cxxi/blob/master/examples/qt/src/QString.cs). But now I'm getting an `AccessViolationException` on the `Marshal.PtrToStringUni`.

```cs
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public unsafe struct QString
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Data
        {
            public int @ref;
            public int alloc, size;
            public IntPtr data;
            public ushort clean;
            public ushort simpletext;
            public ushort righttoleft;
            public ushort asciiCache;
            public ushort capacity;
            public ushort reserved;
            public IntPtr array;
        }

        public Data* d;
        #endregion

        public override string ToString()
        {
            try
            {
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(d->array, d->alloc * 2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, I know I'm looking in the right direction, because omitting the original `drawText` function call in the hook leads to not rendering the text in the target application. It might be some reconfiguration of the struct I posted earlier to get the memory address the string is stored on. The `QPoint.d.alloc` contains the number of characters the string has on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful article https://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html, which explains the QString data structure in Qt5 I've managed to get the hook working:

```cs
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public unsafe struct QString
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct QStringData
        {
            public int @ref;
            public int size;
            public uint alloc;
            public uint capacityReserved;
            public fixed byte data[128];
        }

        public QStringData* data;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            try
            {
                var bytes = new byte[data->size * 2];
                Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)data->data, bytes, 0, data->size * 2);
                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

QString is the complex type.
You can try to import `QString::FromUtf16` for create QString and pass IntPtr to your function

```
string str = "Test";
var p2 = new IntPtr(QString.Utf16(str,str.Length));
```

EDIT: Also, you can try https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp for this

Comment: I'm looking to do this the other way around: I'm not calling the QPainter::drawText function, I'm hooking it and getting the IntPtr. I want to convert the IntPtr to a QString c# structure to get the string.